# Format specific value within JavaScript array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I need to write a JavaScript function that takes the below array and reformats the `price` value from string to number. I cannot use the `=>` or `map` functions.

Current:

```
[{
    item_id: '470',
    item_name: 'producta',
    price: '118.00'
}, {
    item_id: '480',
    item_name: 'productb',
    price: '120.00'
}]
```

Required output:

```
[{
    item_id: '470',
    item_name: 'producta',
    price: 118.00 // number format
}, {
    item_id: '480',
    item_name: 'productb',
    price: 120.00 // number format
}]
```

Comment: What is the reason why you "cannot use the => or map functions"?

Comment: I'm writing the function in google tag manager and it apparently doesn't like these options. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `for` loop and convert the property to a number using the unary plus operator.

```js
var arr = [
  {
    item_id: '470',
    item_name: 'producta',
    price: '118.00'
  },
  {
    item_id: '480',
    item_name: 'productb',
    price: '120.00'
  }
];
for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) arr[i].price = +arr[i].price;
console.log(arr);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{max-height:100%!important;top:0!important;}
```

Comment: thanks iota, any chance you could re-write without using "const" ?  many thanks

Comment: Sure. Just replace it with var. I've updated my answer.

Comment: ah sorry, also looks like gtm doesn't like the for , doesn't like anything within ECMASCRIPT6 framework.

Comment: thank you for this, this is now working, many thanks

Comment: @jromero No problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `for-loop` to iterate over the objects, and `Number` to convert the `price`:

```js
var data = [ 
  { item_id: '470', item_name: 'producta', price: '118.00' },
  { item_id: '480', item_name: 'productb', price: '120.00' } 
];

for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  data[i]['price'] = Number(data[i]['price']);
}

console.log(data);
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer, looks like "const" and "let" are also not going to work for me, could you redo using standard vars?

Comment: @jromero replacing them would be enough. I updated the answer

Comment: thanks unfortunately it still doesn't work with the "for" - I believe GTM doesn't like anything based on ECMASCRIPT6 object destructing (a vague error message in GTM) - is there another way to write this?

Comment: @jromero I'm sure there's something wrong if it doesn't accept the for loop :/ I removed everything related to ES6

Comment: thanks very much this works now, much appreciated